# Cant set the value of razor edit when adding it through javascript

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am trying to set some value of razor editor   `@Html.Editor("PurchaseNo", New With {.htmlAttributes = New With {.value = javavariable}})` through javascript. Purpose of this is to get data on http post. I have created a dynamic table in my project and I want those data in HTTP POST. value of editor is assigning from the array of java. Any solution for it

Comment: You cant. Razor code is server side code and is parsed on the server before its sent to the view. A client side javascript variable does not even exist at that point.

Answer (score 1):

Razor is server side code, so you simply cannot do this.

You could manipulate the rendered HTML that it has produced however.

Comment: Ok I got it but when I use simple `<input type = "text" id ="xyz" value = "somejavascriptvariable"/> `I dont get the value of it on controller while using `Request.Form()`